# How to retain link color in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

While accessing the href links in our application using IE6, the color is getting changed. Even after visiting other menus/pages and returning back to the old page, the visited links changed colors are retained.

Example:

i. Accessed the Page A which has links 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

ii. The links 1, 2, 3 are clicked and its color is changed.

iii. Accessed the Page B and again accessing the Page A.

IE6:    iv. Already visited links 1, 2, 3 colors are retained. i.e. the color of links 1, 2, 3 is different from links 4, 5.

IE8:   iv. Already visited links 1, 2, 3 colors are not retained. i.e. the color of links 1,2,3 is same as links 4, 5.

We would like to retain the color in IE8. Please suggesst how to handle this.

Some more info: Need to have similar to Google site behaviour. Please suggest.

- In Google:

  1. Search something and click few links
  2. Close the window/tab or access some other page
  3. Again open new window/tab and search the same, the already visited pages will be shown in purple color.

Comment: have you tried the `:visited` pseudo class http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Ex: `a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover { color: red; }`

Comment: @Arun: Yes, tried with above mentioned css, it is working fine only in the same page...If I access some other pages and coming back to this page, then it is not working as expected...

Comment: kindly share your code with css

Comment: The "visited link" functionality is completely up to the browser. It's strange that IE8 isn't showing the links you mention as visited, but there is nothing you can do about that on HTML/CSS/JS side. You could check the Internet options in IE8 if there is an option that controls this, but as far as I know there isn't. Why do you need this? It's unusual that a web developer needs this to work the same in different browsers - mostly because it simply is different in different browsers and there is nothing you can do about that.